# Progressive Filtering in Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have an image in Pixi.js, and I want to apply a filter to it. This is simple enough, but I want the filter to actually change the image, so that the next frame, what is rendered is a filtered filtered image, and so on. How do I create a Pixi object that renders to itself every frame?

I found [this](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/33688-applying-filter-to-a-texture-without-clearing-it/), which seems to be asking a similar question, but I cannot make sense of the code provided or the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `PIXI.RenderTexture` class to create an in-memory image and render to it what you want. The render texture will preserve what you've rendered previously.

Here is an example that does that: http://pixijs.io/examples/#/demos/render-texture-demo.js

Here are the docs: http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.RenderTexture.html

Note: To preserve contents when rendering to a texture you need to tell PIXI to not to clear the texture before rendering to it. The below line is from the linked example and the `false` value does just that:

```
...
app.renderer.render(app.stage, renderTexture2, false);
...
```